# Uso del operador and (&&) como simplificación del condicional if en php

Tags: php, condiciones, if

Con la intención de simplificar mi código uso el operador `&&` en lugar de un `if`, y me salto la duda de si eso trae alguna repercusión ya en producción.
un fragmento de mi código:

```
array_key_exists( 'cedula', $columns ) && $this->model->columns[] = 'codigo';
array_key_exists( 'nombres', $columns ) && $this->model->columns[] = 'nombres';
array_key_exists( 'apellido', $columns ) && $this->model->columns[] = [ 'apellido1', 'apellido2' ];
array_key_exists( 'nombre_completo', $columns ) && $this->model->columns[] = [ 'nombres', 'apellidos' ];
```

uso eso en lugar de un **`if`** para cada caso

```
if (array_key_exists( 'cedula', $columns )) {
    $this->model->columns[] = 'codigo';
}
```

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con repercusión en producción?

Comment: Para ser honesto, no creo que eso simplifique el código, mas bien lo oscurece. Pensá que muchas veces tu código tiene que ser leído por otros y cuanto mas claro es más le vas a simplificar la vida. Si va un if, poné un if. Y también te vas a ahorrar dolores de cabeza cuando tengas que modificar ese código agregando condiciones adicionales o  algo más que una simple asignación de valor.

Comment: En todo caso tenés: $this->model->columns[] = (array_key_exists( 'cedula', $columns ) ) ? 'codigo' : ''; que ocupa una sola linea, queda claro lo que se está haciendo, y asignas un valor default empty si la condición no se cumple.

Comment: Eso no mejora el tiempo de ejecucion. Realiza exactamente la misma cantidad de operaciones. Lo que si hace es dificil de leer el código. Recomiendo el uso del `if` como debe ser.

Comment: ¿Y... esa línea: `array_key_exists( 'cedula', $columns ) && $this->model->columns[] = 'codigo';` no da **error**, no faltan paréntesis?

Answer (score 0):

No, la evaluacion de la siguiente condicion, asignacion del valor ( $this->model->columns[] = 'codigo' ), ocurre una vez que array_key_exists retorna true.

Answer (score 0):

**En general**: 
Si bien la [evaluación perezosa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluaci%C3%B3n_perezosa) tiene alguna ventaja de desempeño, claramente sacrifica la legibilidad de código y en consecuencia su mantenibilidad. Antes que decir "nunca" o "siempre" hay que evaluar el contexto: En un servidor con escasos recursos y con sólo un desarrollador preferirás desempeño, en caso inverso preferirás mantenibilidad. Pregunta retórica: ¿Qué es más importante es para tí y para tus usuarios?

**En tu caso particular**:
Ganas tal vez un ciclo de reloj, no más.